# quotient module involving sums

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A,B,C,M$ be modules over a ring $R$ and such that $M$ is cyclic, $A,B,C\subseteq M$, and $A\subseteq B$. Is there any condiction to guarantee that $\frac{A+C}{B+C} \cong \frac{A}{B}$??

Can we get anything if we know that $\frac{A}{B}$ is indecomposable?

Answer (score 1):

You always have a map from $\frac{A}{B}$ to $\frac{A+C}{B+C}$. This map is always surjective.  Kernel is $\frac{ A \bigcap C} {B \bigcap C }$.

So your criterion is $A \bigcap C \subset B$

It is not important that M is cyclic.

Comment: I can agree that $M$ cyclic is not important. But, What about the condition that the quotient is indecomposable? Anyway, I don't believe that this is the kernel, since it is not contained in $\frac{A}{B}$.

Comment: First of all be sure that you understand difference between indecomposable and irreducible.

Let $A = \mathbb{Z} /4\mathbb{Z}$, $B = 0$, $C = 2 (\mathbb{Z} /4\mathbb{Z})$. Then $C$ is the kernel. Notice that $A/B$ is indecomposable.